# In Powershell, how do I concatenate one property of an array of objects into a string?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, join

For example, I have 3 files in c:\z

```
PS C:\z> dir | select name

Name
----
a.png
b.png
c.png
```

What I want is a string.

> a.png,b.png,c.png

Thanks.

Comment: Really Helpful Article -  [Tell Me More: Expanding Objects and Properties in PowerShell](https://www.petri.com/expanding-objects-properties-powershell)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want an array of strings, all you have to do is to:

```
dir | select -expand name
```

If you want that as a single string with the values comma separated:

```
(dir | select -expand name) -join ","
```

Comment: Even Shorter - you can also simply treat the variable as a single object and just specify a property name. i.e. PowerShell will automatically expand `dir.name` into the same thing as `dir | Select -ExpandProperty name`.

Answer (score 10):

Just a small improvement, you can get names only with the Name switch:

```
(dir -name) -join ','
```